# Show one value as Column and Other AS Value in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have the following query,

```
SELECT  AT.Name AS Name, COALESCE(VAL.Value, VALP.Value) AS Value
FROM    Attributes AT
        LEFT OUTER JOIN AttributesValues VAL ON VAL.AttributeID = AT.ID 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN AttributesValues VALP ON VALP.AttributeID = AT.ID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Products p ON p.ID = VAL.ProductID 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN AttributesGroups G ON G.ID = AT.GroupID
ORDER BY p.ID;
```

What I am looking is show Name as Column and Value as Column Value. For example,

```
Name1  | Name2  | Name3
-----------------------
Value1 | Value2 | Value3
```

Comment: Did you try `pivot` table??

Comment: You can try this by using **pivot**  function...
Check these links...

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/548618/PivotplusExampleplusinplusSQLplusServer
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/500811/Simple-Way-To-Use-Pivot-In-SQL-Query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this works for your situation best..

```
CREATE TABLE #temp(Name varchar(25),value varchar(25))
INSERT #temp VALUES('a',1),('b',2),('c',3),('d',4),('e',4),('f',5)
```

---

First create a comma seperated string for you name, so you can use it as columns in pivot.

```
DECLARE @CommoSeperatedNames varchar(max)
SELECT @CommoSeperatedNames=STUFF((SELECT ',' + s.Name FROM #temp s ORDER BY s.Name FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')
```

---

This query uses pivot, here i use dynamic query to get all column names from variable above.

```
Execute( 'select '+@CommoSeperatedNames+' from #temp
pivot 
(
    MIN(value)
    FOR Name
  IN ('+ @CommoSeperatedNames+')
) as TST')
```

If we print the above dynamic query it output following statements.

```
select a,b,c,d,e,f from #temp
pivot 
(
    MIN(value)
    FOR Name
  IN (a,b,c,d,e,f)
) as TST
```

output:

```
a   b   c   d   e   f
1   2   3   4   4   5
```